# How to access HTML checkbox in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, extjs

I have the requirement to dynamicall render an HTML checkbox using extjs and verify whether the checkbox is checked or not.
Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have an id for the checkbox you could just do this Ext.get('idname').dom.checked, it will return true or false

Comment: If you have ExtJS, why would you want to use an HTML checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "renderer" event in listeners and check if checked or not.Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/2644/

```
  renderer:function(value,metaData,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){
          return "<input type='radio' id='"+rowIndex+"' name='check'          "+record.data.radio+">";        
                    },
```